# NoneType() > NoneType() error while dealing with Binary tree

Tags: python, nonetype

When i try to compile it gives me this error[image: NoneType() < NoneType()], i think its because of the max function i used, can someone help me to resolve this?
                                                                                                                         class BinaryTree:
    def **init**(self):
        self.root = None
        self.size = 0

```
# Return True if the element is in the tree
def search(self, e):
    current = self.root # Start from the root

    while current != None:
        if e < current.element:
            current = current.left
        elif e > current.element:
            current = current.right
        else: # element matches current.element
            return True # Element is found

    return False

# Insert element e into the binary search tree
# Return True if the element is inserted successfully
def insert(self, e):
    if self.root == None:
      self.root = self.createNewNode(e) # Create a new root
    else:
      # Locate the parent node
      parent = None
      current = self.root
      while current != None:
        if e < current.element:
          parent = current
          current = current.left
        elif e > current.element:
          parent = current
          current = current.right
        else:
          return False # Duplicate node not inserted

      # Create the new node and attach it to the parent node
      if e < parent.element:
        parent.left = self.createNewNode(e)
      else:
        parent.right = self.createNewNode(e)

    self.size += 1 # Increase tree size
    return True # Element inserted

# Create a new TreeNode for element e
def createNewNode(self, e):
  return TreeNode(e)

def leaf(self):
    self.leafHelper(self.root)

def leafHelper(self,r):
    if r == None:
        return r
    else:
        self.leafHelper(r.left)
        if(r.left == None and r.right == None):
            print(r.element, end = " ")
        self.leafHelper(r.right)

def nonleaf(self):
    self.nonleafHelper(self.root)

def nonleafHelper(self,r):
    if r == None:
        return r
    else:
        self.nonleafHelper(r.left)
        if(r.left != None or r.right != None):
            print(r.element, end = " ")
        self.nonleafHelper(r.right)

def getHeight(self):
    self.height(self.root)

def height(self,r):
    if r == None:
        return r
    else:
        return 1 + max(self.height(r.left),self.height(r.right))

"""
# Return the size of the tree
def getSize(self):
  return self.size"""

# Inorder traversal from the root
def inorder(self):
  self.inorderHelper(self.root)

# Inorder traversal from a subtree
def inorderHelper(self, r):
  if r != None:
    self.inorderHelper(r.left)
    print(r.element, end = " ")
    self.inorderHelper(r.right)

# Postorder traversal from the root
def postorder(self):
  self.postorderHelper(self.root)

# Postorder traversal from a subtree
def postorderHelper(self, root):
  if root != None:
    self.postorderHelper(root.left)
    self.postorderHelper(root.right)
    print(root.element, end = " ")

# Preorder traversal from the root
def preorder(self):
  self.preorderHelper(self.root)

# Preorder traversal from a subtree
def preorderHelper(self, root):
  if root != None:
    print(root.element, end = " ")
    self.preorderHelper(root.left)
    self.preorderHelper(root.right)


# Return true if the tree is empty
def isEmpty(self):
  return self.size == 0

# Remove all elements from the tree
def clear(self):
  self.root == None
  self.size == 0

# Return the root of the tree
def getRoot(self):
  return self.root

class TreeNode:
def __init__(self, e):
  self.element = e
  self.left = None # Point to the left node, default None
  self.right = None # Point to the right node, default None

####################### Main test binary tree


def main(size = 7):
tree = BinaryTree()
tree.insert("George")
tree.insert("Michael")
tree.insert("Tom")
tree.insert("Adam")
tree.insert("Jones")
tree.insert("Peter")
tree.insert("Daniel")

# Traverse tree
print("Inorder (sorted): ", end = "")
tree.inorder()
print("\nPostorder: ", end = "")
tree.postorder()
print("\nPreorder: ", end = "")
tree.preorder()
print("\nLeaf: ", end = "")
tree.leaf()
print("\nNonleaf: ", end = "")
tree.nonleaf()
tree.getHeight()


numbers =[49, 76, 67, 29, 75, 18, 4, 83, 87, 40]
print ("\n\nInserting the following values:")
for i in numbers:
    print(i, end=" ")
print()   
intTree = BinaryTree()
for e in numbers:
  intTree.insert(e)
print("\nPreorder traversal:")
intTree.preorder()
print("\n\nInorder traversal:")
intTree.inorder()
print("\n\nPostorder traversal:")
intTree.postorder()
print("\nLeaf: ", end = "")
intTree.leaf()
print("\nNonleaf: ", end = "")
intTree.nonleaf()
```

if **name** == "**main**":
    main()

Answer (score 1):

Change your `height()` function as follows -

```
def height(self,r):
    if not r:
        return 0
    else:
        return 1 + max(self.height(r.left),self.height(r.right))
```

You can not add a `NoneType` to an `Integer`.